# I am using Prestashop and i need to find certain css file and change it can you help me?

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHTZU.png)

Hello, I need to remove product descriptions from the same category module but couldn't find the module's css file. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following files and update the css according to you themes/[themename]/assests/css/theme.css